# Search Result Webpart showing "People who've written about"

Tags: search-results, enterprise-search

We have SharePoint 2013 and I was tasked to investigate the following issue with Search Result Webpart.

If you do a people search we get the result, but above the result we see:
**People who've written about {User Name Results}** as shown below:

[image]

I have been asked to investigate why it is displaying this message? above the result item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is tripping the out of the box "People Expertise Search" Query rule. You will find the definition in the SSA (or Site Collection) Query Rules under "Local People Results".
[image]

Comment: Thanks Matthew...I have checked both rules (site collection and SSA) and it is steup to: Stop

Comment: So is it fixed? Did I answer your question?

Comment: No...it is still happening even though the settings is "Stop". I did find it strange that it happens when you search using one term, for example if I search for full name it won't show up.

Comment: You need to deactivate the rule..