# Hide 'People named' section in search results

Tags: search, query

I'm building a custom search page for a document library, I've defined this query for it :

```
{searchboxquery} (contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True) Path:https://pathtolobrary
```

The search is specifically meant to search though only this library.
For some reason on some query it displays a 'People named "something"' field. I want to completely get rid of this because it makes no sense at all in this page. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a Query Rule. You can disable the rule at the Site or Site Collection level. It is similar to this question: [Search Result Webpart showing "People who've written about"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135788/search-result-webpart-showing-people-whove-written-about/135882#135882)

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The first part is right. The similar question is pretty much useless wrt this question.
this is what to do:

-go to site settings, 
-query rules,
-select a result source (I took All sources), 
-find the row 'People Name in Sharepoint search' 
- hover it to show the dropdown,
 -then make inactive

thanks!

Comment: So do I get an answer for helping?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to modify the query rule. By default it includes the "People Name in Sharepoint Search". You will have to inactive the People Name in sharepoint Search.

Go to Site Collection -> query rule -> Select source -> "People Name in sharepoint Search" mark it inactive.